# Google Sheets - How to write a formula that minuses the selected cells from the top cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would I do it so if I had a list of numbers, how could I get every number below `A1` to be minuses from `A1` and put next to that cell?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paste** this in `B2` or see the [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/139i1HgpPAFpoH6LFGewYfsfQ97RsaSF491elFWUvXQE/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A-$A$1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple formula in `A2` cell?

```
=INDEX(A1+B2:B6)
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `=INDEX(B2:B6-A1)` or even better `=INDEX(IF(B2:B11="",,B2:B11-A1))`. Or maybe `=INDEX(IF(A2:A11="",,A2:A11-A1))`